# Trying to call a Function inside a stored procedure in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

i am trying to call a function from stored procedure in Oracle, but not getting any idea how to do.
my function has two IN parameter and one OUT parameter.
in my procedure i am using out sys refcursor . Any refrence or example will help me a lot.

Comment: Functions with OUT parameters are bad practice. What is the relationship between what the function returns and the query you open in the sys_refcursor? It's hard for us to write an example without understanding what your code is meant to do. As for references, have you [read the PL/SQL Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/subprograms.htm#LNPLS99952)?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example for calling function inside procedure. Also as mentioned by APC using `OUT` in function is a bad practice. Instead you can `return` your required output. And I'm not sure how you are using `sys_refcursor`, so modify your procedure accordingly

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION SUM_OF_2(NUM1 IN NUMBER,NUM2 IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER
 IS
    RESULT_SUM NUMBER;
    BEGIN
       RESULT_SUM:=NUM1+NUM2;
       RETURN RESULT_SUM;
    END;



CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CALL_FUNCTON(NUM1 NUMBER,NUM2 NUMBER)
AS
    V_FINAL_RESULT NUMBER;
    BEGIN
        V_FINAL_RESULT:=SUM_OF_2(NUM1,NUM2);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(V_FINAL_RESULT);
    END;

BEGIN
 CALL_FUNCTON(5,10);
END;
/
```

[**CHECK DEMO HERE**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c8bc78f8687f6bf1a18ebd3cc70aaebd)

Comment: you are not using any OUT parameter in the function and just using a return

Comment: @SanchitLatawa, Yes. I wouldn't recommend using `OUT` parameter in function.

Comment: To clarify the question was specifically around using OUT parameter and not showing use of return in Functions,so with my code snippet I have tried to show a sample usage. Agreed that Oracle says its a Bad practice.

Comment: @SanchitLatawa, Yes I understand that. But to clarify further, OP's main motive is how to call a function inside a procedure. He was not asking how to create a function with OUT parameter. Also If you see the parameter in question,OP also mentioned 2 IN parameter and your code snippet doesn't even have 1 IN. So i felt the parameter is not a main concern here :)

Answer (score 1):

*Not sure on what your requirement is , maybe you are just trying the code for education purposes. Generally I have not seen much code which uses OUT parameter with functions, in case you want to return multiple values to the caller object then you could use a procedure with more then one OUT variables. There are some limitation on how an oracle function with OUT parameter would differ from a normal function.*

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION temp_demo_func(out_var1 OUT NUMBER)
   RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
BEGIN
   out_var1 := 1;
   RETURN 'T';
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
      RETURN 'F';
END temp_demo_func;
/



CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE temp_demo_proc
(
   in_var1        NUMBER
  ,cur_refcur_out OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
) IS
   res      VARCHAR2(1);
   out_var1 NUMBER;

BEGIN

   res := temp_demo_func(out_var1 => out_var1);

   dbms_output.put_line(out_var1);

   OPEN cur_refcur_out FOR
      SELECT in_var1
            ,out_var1
            ,res
        FROM dual;

END;
/


set serveroutput on
declare
cur_refcur_out  Sys_Refcursor;
in_var1 number := 22;
begin 

temp_demo_proc(in_var1 => in_var1
               ,cur_refcur_out => cur_refcur_out);

end;
/
```